# Incomplete API response for getUsers

Tags: docusignapi

I'm implementing an API integration for DocuSign, and I'm currently hitting the following endpoint: `/v2/organizations/{organizationId}/users`

The documentaton for this: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/users/users/getusers/#response200_docusign.api.organizations.web.models.restapi.v2.response.organizationuserresponse

The documentation is showing a response field, `user_status`. However, when I call the API, I get a response as follows:

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "id":"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
         "user_name":"Xxxx",
         "first_name":"",
         "last_name":"Xxxx",
         "membership_status":"active",
         "email":"xxxx@gmail.com",
         "membership_created_on":"2021-07-30T02:24:20.243",
         "membership_id":"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
      },
      {
         "id":"yyy-yyy-yyy-yyy-yyy",
         "user_name":"Yyyyy",
         "first_name":"Yyyyy",
         "last_name":"2",
         "membership_status":"active",
         "email":"yyyyyyy@yyy.yyy",
         "membership_created_on":"2021-07-30T02:26:59.313",
         "membership_id":"yyy-yyy-yyy-yyy-yyy"
      },
      {
         "id":"zzz-zzz-zzz-zzz-zzz",
         "user_name":"Zzzzz",
         "first_name":"Zzzz",
         "last_name":"Zzzz",
         "membership_status":"active",
         "email":"zzz@zzz-zzz.net",
         "membership_created_on":"2021-07-15T04:05:18.803",
         "membership_id":"zzz-zzz-zzz-zzz-zzz"
      }
   ],
   "paging":{
      "result_set_size":3,
      "result_set_start_position":0,
      "result_set_end_position":2,
      "total_set_size":3
   }
}
```

As you can see, we have no `user_status`. Do we need to send any request parameters, to expand the response, or has this field been removed from the API response without being updated on the API documentation?

Or, could I assume that the user is active, if it appears in the API response, with a membership_status of `active`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect there may be an issue with the documentation. When are you trying to do? if you see the diagram I posted in your other question, you'll see the "Members" (or "Memberships") are a combination of a user and an account. A user can be a member of more than one account. The user can be active in one account and the same user may not be active in another account. So the membership status is what you really need. The user status is not that useful (and I'm not sure how you get it but I'll check)

Answer (score 0):

**membership_status** is probably what you're looking for.

there's no such thing as **user_status** because a user can be a member of multiple accounts and each membership can have a different status.

Here is a useful diagram:

[image]